# How can I make a triangle of hashes upside-down in python

Tags: python, function, hash, triangle

I have to do a hash triangle using this function:

```
def line(num=int, word=str):
   if word == "":
       print("*" * num)
   else:
       print(word[0] * num)
```

Here is the code i have:

```
def line(num=int, word=str):
    if word == "":
        print("*" * num)
    else:
        print(word[0] * num)

def triangle(size):
    # You should call function line here with proper parameters
    
    while size > 0:
        
        line(size, "#")
        size -= 1
```

the output is this:

```
######
#####
#### 
###  
##   
#
```

but it should be this:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
```

how can i modify it so it prints that?

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. `i` controls the number of `#` symbols that will be printed on each line, right? So, if you want the first line to have one symbol, what should `i` be equal to the first time through the loop? Therefore, how should we set `i` before the loop? Should the number of symbols on each line increase, or decrease? Therefore, what should happen to `i` each time through the loop? When we are done with the triangle, what can we say about the value of `i`? Therefore, how can we control the loop to finish the triangle?

Comment: Please try to solve problems yourself before asking. This is not a tutoring service. Programming is fundamentally about thinking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are starting from size and going to 1 you should do the opposite:

```
i = 0
while i <= size:
    i += 1
    ...
```

Also `for i in range(1, size + 1)` would be more pythonic ;)

Comment: i know but for some reason they refuse to teach for

Comment: i get a square now

Comment: Call line(i, "#") ;)

Answer (score -1):

Slightly adjusted your code

```
def line(num=int, word=str):
  if word == "":
    print("*" * num)
  else:
    print(word[0] * num)

def triangle(size):
  # You should call function line here with proper parameters
  charPerLine = 1
  while charPerLine <= size:
      line(charPerLine, "#")
      charPerLine += 1
        
        
triangle(5)
```